# CMake error when compiling OpenCV with extra modules

Tags: windows, cmake, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I'm working (more like trying to work as you'll see in a moment) on a project with OpenCV and I'm having issues with the compilation of the OpenCV framework with the extra modules. (I know you can get pre-compiled libraries from OpenCV site but I'd like to use the 3.1 version with the missing modules from 2.4).

The issue I'm experiencing lies with CMake, I've been trying to make it work for a few days but to no avail. What I'm trying to do, as you've probably guessed, is to build the OpenCV 3.1 framework with the extra modules (contrib branch, that is).

I've seen in other questions that usually the issue is with the VS2015 (community versione for me) installation which is missing the C++ component. I already made sure that wasn't the case by clean-installing the whole thing.

In other answers I've also seen people suggesting to launch cmake from VS itself and select the correct compiler but that didn't seem to work either (correct me if I'm wrong but the C++ compiler is the cl.exe inside the VS14/VC/bin folder).

Now, at this point pretty much everyone seems to have fixed the issue with one of the previous steps, sadly it's not my case since CMake is still giving me errors which are the ones shown below:

- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
- The C compiler identification is unknown
- CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_88b12.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"
- The C++ compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Those are the outputs I'm getting inside the CMake-gui (doesn't matter if I run it from VS or not) when passing the C++ compiler by hand, listed above, since the default native compiler doesn't find a compiler at all.

In the CMakeError file I get this:

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   Impossibile trovare il file specificato
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
>   Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
>   Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   Impossibile trovare il file specificato
>
> Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
>   Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
>   Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: C:/OpenCV/OpenCV/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_5281c.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"
>
> Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_5281c.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"

Onto the question now: has anyone got the slightest idea of what's wrong? I'm quite sure I'm missing something really simple (especially since it doesn't seem to recognize the compiler that I'm using) but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I apologize for the long post and any formatting issue.

Thanks in advance for the help you guys can provide, hopefully I can finally make the thing work with your help.